# Is it possible to display "Display Name" in TFS Source Control?

Tags: version-control, tfs, userid

Our company uses a 'user number' for our primary network ID.  We do use Active Directory for managing our users, so we can associate our user number with a Display Name.

TFS Source Control by default (only?) shows a User column, which shows the network ID.  Is it possible to add/show the Display Name in TFS Source Control instead of, or with a user's network ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately this is not possible.

Comment: That's frustrating - TFS Work Items allow selection of, and display Display Names.  I'm really surprised Source Control does not.

Comment: True, but Work Items have the opposite problem -- there's no way to select or display your email alias.